# returning total records in cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

With help from [article here](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2008/11/paging-with-ranking-functions.html?m=1) and recent answers from SO experts I have arrived with the following which will help me efficiently page through a set of records.

I think my last couple of questions are

1. See how I include the `Total Number of Records` in the payload at the end
   of SQL CTE called 'Total'. Is that how you would do this?
2. Any other suggestions? Potential areas for being more concise or improvements? `Return Total Number of Pages`

---

```
DECLARE @page_size INT = 5;
DECLARE @page_nbr INT = 4;
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @sort_order INT = 2;

WITH AllProducts
AS
(
SELECT *, 
CASE @sort_order
    WHEN 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProductID )
    WHEN 2 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProductName )
END AS 'Seq'    
FROM Products
),
Filtered
AS
(
SELECT * FROM AllProducts
WHERE ProductName like '%'+@search+'%'
OR
@search is null
)
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from Filtered) as 'Total', * FROM Filtered
WHERE seq > (@page_nbr - 1) * @page_size
  AND seq <= @page_nbr * @page_size
```

Comment: how did you do that? normally i don't have an issue pasting sql. please delete my image then.

Comment: If your code appears inside a blockquote or a list, you must indent a further four spaces for every level of nesting. Since that was too time-consuming i've simply added a horizontal rule to break the list.

Comment: Thanks for helping me ask for help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's something wrong in your query: it numbers records (for paging) and after that applies the filter.

It is, for example, possible that you request page 2 of records, but all records with the corresponding `seq` values could be filtered out in the meantime. So, in this case the query would yield no results, although there may be plenty of records in the table.

In order to fix that, you could do the filtering and record numbering in the same CTE, like this:

```
DECLARE @page_size INT = 5;
DECLARE @page_nbr INT = 4;
DECLARE @search NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @sort_order INT = 2;

WITH Filtered AS (
    SELECT *, 
        CASE @sort_order
            WHEN 1 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProductID )
            WHEN 2 THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ProductName )
        END AS 'Seq'
    FROM AllProducts
    WHERE ProductName like '%'+@search+'%' OR @search is null
)
SELECT (select COUNT(*) from Filtered) as 'Total', * FROM Filtered
WHERE seq > (@page_nbr - 1) * @page_size
  AND seq <= @page_nbr * @page_size
```